# How to check data from dynamical url request php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, .htaccess

I am practicing to create a CMS. I set all of url request to `index.php`. And I take the request data by `$path` variable.

**.htAccess**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [QSA,L]
```

So, I get the data on `$path` and make a `sql` request to `echo` data on the page. My `sql` table had 2 column `data` and `url`. So, my code was:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM post where url='" . $path . "'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
if(is_array($row)) {
    echo $row["data"];
}
```

But problem start when I create the category, I think I have to add one new column `ctg` so I made it.Now when I get request like `localhost/php/how-to-make-a-page` , then I think I have to do like this:

```
if (strpos($path, '/') !== false) {
        $array = explode("/", $path);
        $url = end($array);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM post where url='" . $url . "'";
    }
```

But I was very child about this this thinking. Because `localhost/php/how-to-make-a-page` and `localhost/Anything/how-to-make-a-page` give me the same result. Please can anyone explain about handling this type request?

Answer (score 0):

My advice is that you start with an easy to learn framework, how is it "[codeigneiter](https://codeigniter.com/)", while you go documenting you will understand what is a route, controller, model, among others. Now regarding your code, you are not grouping categories, for that you should have a syntax in this way, "category / php / how-to-make-a-page" and a query like this: "SELECT * FROM post WHERE category =" php "AND url =" how-to-make-a-page "and the php example would be:

```
<?php
 $parts_of_url = explode('/', $path);
 if($parts_of_url[0] === 'category') {
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM post where category_id= :category_id AND url= :url";
 }
?>
```

Check what are parameters in a sql statement here http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

But I will insist that if you want to learn well how routes work, queries with database, driver, form validations. Well, you should consult the framework I mentioned earlier.